# jqGrid embedded in a custom User Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a simple custom user control that uses jqGrid. the control is as in the following code:

Markup:

```
<div id="grid_container" runat="server">
    <table id="umlt_grid" runat="server"></table>
    <div id="umlt_grid_pager" runat="server"></div>
</div>
<div id="umlt_dialog" title="Umlt" style="display: none;" runat="server"></div>
```

Script (inside the ascx file)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Initialize controls
        var dialogID = $('#<%=umlt_dialog.ClientID %>');
        var dlg = $(dialogID);
        dlg.dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, stack: true, resizable: false, position: 'center', width: 380, height: 260 });
        //Load the Grid
        var gridID = '#<%=umlt_grid.ClientID %>';
        var pagerID = '#<%=umlt_grid_pager.ClientID %>';
        var containerID = '#<%=grid_container.ClientID %>'
        var gridWidth = GetAvailableSpaceBody( $(containerID).width() );
        loadUmltGrid(gridID, pagerID, dlg, gridWidth);
    });
</script>
```

The `loadUmltGrid` function is defined inside a dedicated js file which is loaded through the master page. Here it is:

```
function loadUmltGrid(gridID, pagerID, dialog, gridWidth) {
    var grid = $(gridID);
    var pager = $(pagerID);
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: GetBaseWSUrl() + 'UmltService.asmx/ListUmlts',
        colNames: ['Code', 'Description', 'Note'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 120, template: colTextTemplate },
                    { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 220, template: colTextTemplate },
                    { name: 'Notes', index: 'Notes', width: 300, template: colTextTemplate }
                ],
        jsonReader: {
            id: "UmltID"
        },
        pager: pager,
        sortname: 'Code',
        sortorder: "asc",
        height: '300',
        gridview: true,
        width: gridWidth,
        autowidth: false,
        shrinkToFit: true
    }).jqGrid('navGrid', pagerID,
        { add: true, addtitle: 'Add UMLT',
            edit: true, edittitle: 'Edit UMLT',
            del: true, deltitle: 'Delete UMLT',
            refresh: true, refreshtitle: 'Refresh data',
            search: true, searchtitle: 'Advanced search filters',
            addfunc: function () {
                loadUmltDialog(GetBaseWSUrl() + 'UmltService.asmx/NewUmlt', "", dialog);
            },
            editfunc: function () {
                var rowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                loadUmltDialog(GetBaseWSUrl() + 'UmltService.asmx/EditUmlt', rowId, dialog);
            }
        },
        { /*default settings for edit*/ },
        { /*default settings for add*/ },
        { mtype: "post", reloadAfterSubmit: false,
            url: GetBaseWSUrl() + 'UmltService.asmx/DeleteUmlt',
            resize: false, serializeDelData: function (postdata) { return JSON.stringify({ umltID: postdata.id }); },
            afterSubmit: function (data, postdata) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                if (result.d.StatusResult === "OK") {
                    showInfoMessage(result.d.StatusResult, result.d.StatusDescription);
                } else {
                    showErrorMessage("Error", result.d.StatusDescription);
                }
                return [true, ''];
            }
        },
        { closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true }, {}
    ).jqGrid('navSeparatorAdd', pagerID, {}).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', pagerID, {
        caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-extlink", position: "last", title: "Export to Excel",
        onClickButton: function () {
            window.open(GetCurrentSiteUrl() + '/_layouts/ExportExcel.aspx?View=UMLT');
        }
    });
}
```

I need to use this user control inside a Web Part (SharePoint) and inside another control so I simply added to my project a wrapper web part and included the control inside the other one.

Everything seems to work for the web part as you can see from the following screenshot
[image: User control wrapped in a web part]

but when I use it inside another user control I am experiencing 2 strange problems:

1. The custom "export" button added to the toolbar gets duplicated
2. the pager (Page n of m) is showed aligned to the left

You can see this behaviour in the following screenshot
[image: User control inside another user control]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't included the code of the main function `loadUmltGrid` which defines your grid. So I try just to guess.

Typically the custom buttons from the navigator toolbar come with respect of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) method of jqGrid. The standard buttons come by calling of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator). The problem with multiple custom buttons one have typically if the code which add the buttons will be executed more as one time. You can just insert `alert` before the call of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) and I suppose that you will see the message from the alert **twice**. The [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) has an internal control. If the method will be called at the second time for the same pager it returns immediately. So have no duplicates of the standard buttons event the corresponding code runs multiple times.

The second problem with position of the pager exists typically if you use some small value of the `width` parameter of jqGrid at the beginning and then later increase the grid width with respect of [setGridWidth](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods). I recommend you, before writing of any code which change the position of the middle part of the pager, to increase the initial value of the grid width which you use at the grid initialization.

Comment: Hello Oleg, thanks for your answer. I have edited my question to include the main function that creates the grid. Regarding the second problem you are right: I am changing the grid width at runtime because the grid is included in an hidden control and so the first time he has a zero-width. Do you know any different way to achieve the same result?

Comment: @Lorenzo: What do you mean under "the first time"? When is the second time? If you has hidden control at the beginning why you need to call `loadUmltGrid`? Only if some parent `<div>` like `div#grid_container` you make visible you should call the `loadUmltGrid` function. By the way the `loadUmltGrid` should be called **only once**. Later, after the grid already exist, you should call `$('#umlt_grid').trigger('reloadGrid');` instead. If you not do so you will have for example one more "export" button.

Comment: I just call once `loadUmltGrid` or, better said, I dont call it at all but is called when the user control get rendered. the user control is inside an hidden panel so the `document.ready()` is called automatically when the control is rendered the first time. To adjust this I am successfully calling `setGridWidth` when the control become visible.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Do you tried to insert `alert` inside of `loadUmltGrid` function like I suggested? How many time the method was called: once or twice? If you call somewhere `setGridWidth` you can call on the place the `loadUmltGrid`. Inside of `document.ready()` you should not call `loadUmltGrid` in your case. So my suggestion is not to call `loadUmltGrid` till the grid will be visible.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion. This is not right for me because it does'nt permit me to have a self-contained user-control. ANyway now it's working. Thanks for helping out..

Comment: @Lorenzo: You are welcome! I am glad to read that your problem (at least this one) is solved and that I could help you here.