# How to make JQgrid like web control?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

we have planned to use jqgrid in our application. But, we need to make it as custom web control like below:

Example:

```
<TestGrid:JQGrid ID="grdTest" Sortable="True" runat="server"/>
```

In all examples they create jqgrid in aspx page. Is there any possibility to create the control like above? Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated. Also, Please give me the website link if any available.

Answer (score 2):

Try these two links..it is possoble to use jqGrid as user control(though i never used it that way), but these two links will help you, one of them is answered by Oleg.

[link 1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1656564.aspx/1)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983617/jqgrid-embedded-in-a-custom-user-control)

Comment: Thanks for the links. In that link they used trirand control. Our requirement is exactly same and we need to create control similar to them. I am looking for samples and ideas..